# Create private access to qgis2web maps on Wordpress site

Tags: qgis, javascript, html, qgis2web, wordpress

I want to use Wordpress site and qgis2web plugin to show maps to clients. According to my idea, a user logins to his private page and gets links to his private maps. But when I upload qgis2web folder to my site, everybody with the link can access this folder without authentication. And I can't give access to this folder to specific user, because this folder is not a wordpress page.

I can imagine two approaches of making qgis2web maps private:
1 - making qgis2web folder inaccessible by direct link and accessible from specific page. Does anybody know if it is possible?

2 - converting qgis2web folder (or at least index.html) to wordpress page. It is more than just copying content of index.html to blank page because you must replace all relative links with absolute links or copy content of all js and css. So does anybody know plugin (or third software) that can do it automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have more joy asking this of a Wordpress audience, rather than a GIS one. A search led me to this answer about securing uploads in a Wordpress site:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/37743/65134

Perhaps this might work for you? However, I'm no Wordpress expert.